# Angular 2 form validation pattern regex error

Tags: angular, regex, forms, validation

I'm creating a form in angular that requires the name field only contain alphanumeric characters and spaces. To do this I use the pattern attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="Name" [(ngModel)]="name" required pattern="/^[a-z\d-_\s]+$/i" #nameField="ngModel">
```

and I have the following error message I want to show when the string does not match:

```
<div *ngIf="nameField.errors">
   <div [hidden]="!nameField.errors.pattern">
       <p class="has-error">
          Only spaces, letters, and numbers are allowed.
       </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

However, it seems that even when the string should match the regular expression, I can still see the error message. Any ideas?

Comment: i think it should be something like :  <span  *ngIf="nameField.errors?.pattern"

Comment: Try `pattern="^[\w\s-]+$"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
pattern="^[\w\s-]+$"
```

The `[A-Za-z\d_]` matches the same chars as `\w` in JavaScript native regex. The whole pattern thus matches one or more ASCII letters, digits, underscores, hyphens or white spaces.

Note that angular anchors the pattern by default, but it is preferable to keep the anchors `^` and `$` explicit in the pattern to make it compatible with any other frameworks.

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer. Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: can you please help me to solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52091334/password-validation-is-not-working-in-angular-5 @WiktorStribizew

Answer (score 9):

I guess the issue here is that the syntax of regex not correctly formed:

```
 <form novalidate #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Name" name="Name" 
    [(ngModel)]="name" 
    required pattern="^[A-Z\\a-z\\d-_\\s]+$" 
    #nameField="ngModel" >
    <div>
      <div *ngIf="nameField.errors?.pattern">
        <p class="has-error">
          Only spaces, letters, and numbers are allowed.
        </p>
        hame: {{nameField.errors | json}}
     </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

look at this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bdkl44ZQIthKq95g1wgj?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the help. While your answer worked, The answer bellow you worked a little better for my specific case so I've marked it as the answer.